# Android Studio not picking up the minSdkVersion

Tags: android, api, adapter, manifest

I already have 'android:minSdkVersion="11"' but setRemoteAdapter(..) is still complaining - am i missing something here?

I have already tried "Make Project" and "Rebuild Project"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Whats your Project Build Target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the build.gradle file in the project, the manifest is no the right place / enough.